# Error in unserialize(con) : unknown input format

Tags: r, azure, azure-functions

I am downloading a file from Azure to a connection. The download appears to go through but unserializing gives an error. Any ideas what may be going wrong or how to go about debugging?

```
con <- rawConnection(raw(0), "r+")
storage_download(AzureContainer, src="sourcefile.fst", dest=con)
unserialize(con)
Error in unserialize(con) : unknown input format
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `unserialize`? That function is really only for R's serialization format. If you are just working with a raw csv file, you shouldn't need to unserialize it.

Comment: I am actually reading a .fst file from Azure using the AzureStor package. I am trying to avoid downloading the .fst file first and using ```rawConnection``` and ```unserilaize``` is one of the suggested ways. Link below - github.com/Azure/AzureStor#transfer-to-and-from-connections

Comment: That example uses `unserialize` on an `rds` object which makes sense. That doesn't make sense for a `csv` file though. What if you did `read.csv(con)` instead?

Comment: Well.its a .fst file. Directly reading it via read_fst(con) gives an error too.                     ```> read.fst(con,as.data.table = FALSE)
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument```

Comment: Sounds like the read_fat function requires a file path and cannot read from a connection. Seems like you have to write to disk first then.

Comment: Yes, going back to that approach